# Acess Joomla framework from external php file

Tags: joomla-3.x

Please advise on how to access the Joomla framework in 3.10 using an external php file in Joomla 3 which can work in Joomla 4 too

I am getting this issue:

```
Warning: Constant JPATH_BASE already defined in F:\wamp64\www\16december2022\includes\app.php on line 21
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  367960  {main}( )   ...\getmodel.php:0
2   0.0258  794208  require_once( 'F:\wamp64\www\16december2022\includes\app.php )  ...\getmodel.php:10
3   0.0263  794272  define( $constant_name = 'JPATH_BASE', $value = 'F:\\wamp64\\www\\16december2022' ) ...\app.php:21

( ! ) Warning: file_get_contents(F:\wamp64\www\16december2022/templates/system/build_incomplete.html): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in F:\wamp64\www\16december2022\includes\app.php on line 27
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  367960  {main}( )   ...\getmodel.php:0
2   0.0258  794208  require_once( 'F:\wamp64\www\16december2022\includes\app.php )  ...\getmodel.php:10
3   0.0301  794560  file_get_contents( $filename = 'F:\\wamp64\\www\\16december2022/templates/system/build_incomplete.html' )   ...\app.php:27
```

Code of getmodel.php which is working when using JFactory, but when using Factory not working. I think JFactory is not recommended in Joomla 4x and onwards

```
<?php

define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));  
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/app.php';

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
$mainframe = Factory::getApplication('site');
    
     // GET using JInput
    $jinput  = Factory::getApplication()->input;
    $ModelId = $jinput->get('s', '', 'INT');

    $db = JFactory::getDBO();   
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $query-> function
?>
```

created app.php and modified last line as referred in https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/34586 in includes folder

```
<?php

/**
 * @package    Joomla.Site
 *
 * @copyright  (C) 2017 Open Source Matters, Inc. <https://www.joomla.org>
 * @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// Saves the start time and memory usage.
$startTime = microtime(1);
$startMem  = memory_get_usage();

if (file_exists(dirname(__DIR__) . '/defines.php')) {
    include_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) {
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__DIR__));
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

// Check for presence of vendor dependencies not included in the git repository
if (!file_exists(JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/vendor/autoload.php') || !is_dir(JPATH_ROOT . '/media/vendor')) {
    echo file_get_contents(JPATH_ROOT . '/templates/system/build_incomplete.html');

    exit;
}

require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

// Set profiler start time and memory usage and mark afterLoad in the profiler.
JDEBUG && \Joomla\CMS\Profiler\Profiler::getInstance('Application')->setStart($startTime, $startMem)->mark('afterLoad');

// Boot the DI container
$container = \Joomla\CMS\Factory::getContainer();

/*
 * Alias the session service keys to the web session service as that is the primary session backend for this application
 *
 * In addition to aliasing "common" service keys, we also create aliases for the PHP classes to ensure autowiring objects
 * is supported.  This includes aliases for aliased class names, and the keys for aliased class names should be considered
 * deprecated to be removed when the class name alias is removed as well.
 */
$container->alias('session.web', 'session.web.site')
    ->alias('session', 'session.web.site')
    ->alias('JSession', 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\CMS\Session\Session::class, 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\Session\Session::class, 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\Session\SessionInterface::class, 'session.web.site');

// Instantiate the application.
$app = $container->get(\Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication::class);

// Set the application as global app
\Joomla\CMS\Factory::$application = $app;

// Execute the application.
var_dump($app);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have error reporting turned on and only a warning is breaking things.  Look at the error message - it's simply saying that the constant is already defined.  You need to either turn down the error reporting config in PHP, or rewrite the code to only define `JPATH_BASE` if it's not already.

For example:

```
<?php

if (!defined('_JEXEC')) define('_JEXEC', 1);
if (!defined('JPATH_BASE')) define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);

require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

// Boot the DI container
$container = \Joomla\CMS\Factory::getContainer();

/*
 * Alias the session service keys to the web session service as that is the primary session backend for this application
 *
 * In addition to aliasing "common" service keys, we also create aliases for the PHP classes to ensure autowiring objects
 * is supported.  This includes aliases for aliased class names, and the keys for aliased class names should be considered
 * deprecated to be removed when the class name alias is removed as well.
 */
$container->alias('session.web', 'session.web.site')
    ->alias('session', 'session.web.site')
    ->alias('JSession', 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\CMS\Session\Session::class, 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\Session\Session::class, 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\Session\SessionInterface::class, 'session.web.site');

// Instantiate the application.
$app = $container->get(\Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication::class);

// Set the application as global app
\Joomla\CMS\Factory::$application = $app;

var_dump($app);
```

Comment: Thanks, although error gone but still unable to use joomla framework in external file in 4x. trying with tweaks will let know soon

Comment: thanks, able to work done by slight modifying